# Curious text alignment with iOS MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an app that can send a message (containing a diagnostic dump).  The MFMailComposeViewController appears fine on the simulator, but looks odd on a "old" iPad (haven't tried it on newer).  The iPad is running 5.1.1 and claims to be model MC349LL.

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

As you can see, the "To" text is presented low and gets cut off (the Cc/Bcc text is likewise).  And the "Subject" text is clearly appearing lower than it should be.  On the simulator the text is properly aligned and nothing is cut off.

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: It looks like your Subject may start with a `\n`. Can you show us the code you use to initialize the MFMailComposeViewController?

Comment: The subject is passed in as a parm.  But the "To" address was entered from the keyboard, and you can see it has the same misalignment.

Comment: Do you think this issue is only associated with this 'old' iPad, or is the same with other iPad's too?

Comment: This is interesting. Can't seem to reproduce on 6.0.2 Mini. It looks like this misalignment is happening to every text field including body, as none of yours are aligned the same as mine. Is there anything *funky* about how you're presenting the controller?

Comment: What if to try plain call to MFMailComposer, i.e. not to call it the way you do, but from somewhere else with predefined constant fields?

Comment: I'll see if I can try it on a newer unit in a bit.  It's a little tricky to experiment with different stuff since the email is sent from within a separately compiled framework.

Comment: I have a 5.1.1 iPad Original here, and I'm presenting an MFMailComposer without the effect you're seeing.

Comment: Don't know if you've solved this yet, but if you did I'd be curious to hear how. And if this isn't reproducible on a 5.1.1 iPad as Fis'Zen stated, maybe you just had a corrupt IPSW and a restore is required. Stranger things have happened!

Comment: @0x7fffffff - Unfortunately, when I installed the app on a newer iPad I borrowed, it wasn't set up for email, so I could never get to the screen.  (And I didn't want to monkey with the guy's device.)  I'll try to find another one somewhere.